# Initial values for Redux-Form only rendering when hardcoded, but not from props/state

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, redux-form

In my redux-form, I am trying to initialize a form with data that I am receiving from an API and passing into the component via props. Right now, my initialize function can accept and display strings (i.e. if i pass in `"questionText: "some text"`, that populates the questionText `<Field>)`. However, when I pass in the state of the props I'm accepting, nothing populates.

When I do `"questionText: this.state.offerContent.name"`, nothing displays in the `<Field>`.

I am trying to figure out why this is happening. Here is some relevant code.

```
   constructor(props) {
      super(props)
      this.state = {
        offerContent: ''
      }

  componentDidMount(){
      this.props.offerCallBack()
        .then(c => {
             this.setState({
               offerContent: c,
             });
        })
        .catch(error => {
          console.log(error);
         });
         this.handleInitialize();

        }

        handleInitialize() {
          const initData = {
            "questionText": this.props.offerContent.name,
          };

          this.props.initialize(initData);
        }

              <Field
                  name="questionText"
                  type="text"
                  id="questionText"
                  component={renderField}
                  label="Question Text"
              />

const form = reduxForm({
  form: 'offerquestion',
  enableReinitialize: true

});

function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return {
    offerContent: state.offerContent
}
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(form(OfferExample));
```

**this is what happens when I console.log(this.props) in this OfferExample component: 
[image]

Comment: Shouldnt your mapstatetoProps method contain offerContent: state.offerContent... or some similar line?

Comment: that's what I tried, but then it still does not populate :( @G_S

Comment: But The code you posted doesn't have that line.

Comment: I just tried it locally. I will update my code in my question to include it

Comment: In offerexample component, can you check this.props ?

Comment: in that component, console.log(this.props) outputs the typical props to the console. i'll include it in the updated code in the question

Comment: I see offercontent is null in props

Comment: what should that initially be? maybe that's where my confusion is

Comment: You should be registering your store somewhere in your application. I guess you should have a default initialState there